# Problem saving two models and retrieving a record from the database with Fluent

Tags: swift, vapor, fluent-orm

I'm just getting started with programming and vapor and have the following querying problem.

When a user makes a request to /api/trip/new to create a new trip, I want to retrieve the first driver from the database and assign their ID to a Trip object. Then I want to save both the trip and trip request in the database.

I have the following code:

```
func newTripHandler(_ req: Request, data: TripRequestCreateData) throws -> Future<TripRequest> {
let passenger = try req.requireAuthenticated(Passenger.self)
let tripRequest = try TripRequest(pickupLat: data.pickupLat,
                                  pickupLng: data.pickupLng,
                                  destLat: data.destLat,
                                  destLng: data.destLng,
                                  pickupAddress: data.pickupAddress,
                                  destAddress: data.destAddress,
                                  passengerId: passenger.requireID())

//Passenger's location
let lat = tripRequest.pickupLat
let lng = tripRequest.pickupLng

//Passenger's destination
let toLat = tripRequest.destLat
let toLng = tripRequest.destLng

let trip = Trip(passengerId: tripRequest.passengerId!,
                pickupLat: lat,
                pickupLng: lng,
                destLat: toLat,
                destLng: toLng,
                pickupAddress: tripRequest.pickupAddress,
                destAddress: tripRequest.destAddress)

let driver = Driver.query(on: req).first().unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound))

let driverId = driver.map(to: Driver.self) { driver in
  return driver.id
}

trip.driverId = driverId

print(trip)

return tripRequest.save(on: req)
}

struct TripRequestCreateData: Content {
  let pickupLat: Double
  let pickupLng: Double
  let destLat: Double
  let destLng: Double
  let pickupAddress: String
  let destAddress: String
}
```

I’m not sure how to save two models and how to properly retrieve the driver from the database. The driverId constant is of type EventLoopFuture instead of Driver so I can't assign the ID to trip's driverId property.

How can I adjust my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with the database, you only get `Future`s. (More about `Future`s in [The Vapor Docs](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/async/overview/).)

So to get the driver, you already used the correct code, but have to go on inside the `map` codeblock. When returning a `Future` inside the `map`, use `flatMap`, so you don't have a `Futures` inside `Futures`.

Try this:

```swift
return Driver.query(on: req).first().unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound)).flatMap { driver in
    trip.driverId = driver.id

    return trip.save(on: req).flatMap { trip in
        return tripRequest.save(on: req)
    }
}
```

(I chose this way to show how `Future`s work - there are some ways to make this code cleaner, e.g. chaining `Future`s or using `flatten`.)